# How to get the Fourier series using Python's $\tt fft$

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, python, fourier-series

I Would like to be able to reconstruct every individual sinusoid that makes up a Discrete signal. I Have the following signal: (I am working in Python)
[image]

The signal is essentially an array with about 400 elements that varies with time. In Python after calling the `fft` function on the data

```
 dft= rfft(dat)/len(dat)  #real fft
```

I receive the figure below:
[image]

I am aware that I can use the result of the `fft` to obtain the individual Fourier series components, but I am unsure exactly how. The code I have yields me an array of magnitudes for each harmonic of the signal, how do I use that to get each individual component of the Fourier series?

Comment: now the **Fourier Series** is specifically for periodic signals.  (and the DFT or FFT will directly get your Fourier series coefficients from the sampled periodic signal.)  are you sure your data is periodic?

Comment: Could i just perform a periodic extension on the data?

Comment: yes, you **can**.  and that is **inherently** what happens when you pass your data to the FFT.  the DFT treats your $N$ samples of data supplied as a single period of a periodic function or sequence.  but your data above has a nasty discontinuity between the end (at 2082) and the beginning (at 2091).  periodically extending that data without windowing might look bad after the FFT.

Answer (score 4):

I am no expert in this topic, but have some useful examples to share.

#### 1 component example

To keep the `i`-eth Fourier component, you can zero the rest of the components:

```
n = len(y)
Y = numpy.fft.fft(y)
numpy.put(Y, range(0, i), 0.0)
numpy.put(Y, range(i+1, n), 0.0)
# Now Y holds 1 imaginary coefficient corresponding with the i-eth Fourier component
```

If you're looking for the Real signal corresponding to the chosen `i`-eth component, you can afterwards perform the inverse transform through `ifft`:

```
ifft = numpy.fft.ifft(Y) # the sinusoid you're looking for
```

#### Multiple components example

The more Fourier components you keep, the closer you'll mimic the original signal. This example shows what happens when you keep 10, 20, ...up tp *n* components.

Assuming `x` and `y` are your data vectors.

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = len(y)
COMPONENTS = [10, 20, n]

for c in COMPONENTS:
    colors = numpy.linspace(start=100, stop=255, num=c)
    for i in range(c):
        Y = numpy.fft.fft(y)
        numpy.put(Y, range(i+1, n), 0.0)
        ifft = numpy.fft.ifft(Y)
        plt.plot(x, ifft, color=plt.cm.Reds(int(colors[i])), alpha=.70)

    plt.title("First {c} fourier components".format(c=c))
    plt.plot(x,y, label="Original dataset")
    plt.grid(linestyle='dashed')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image: First 10 Fourier components]
[image: First 20 Fourier components]
[image: First 306 Fourier components]

...see how it mimics the original signal?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that your signal is one period of the original signal, then the FFT gives you the Fourier Series coefficients up to frequency $F_s/2$ (due to Nyquist theorem). The DFT result are exactly the coefficients of the complex Fourier Series. You can convert the complex coefficients to $a_n$ and $b_n$ of the real Fourier series (with sines and cosines) according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series). Also, two of my articles ([Complex Fourier Series](http://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/the-complex-fourier-series-and-its-relation-to-the-fourier-transform.html), [Spectral Leakage](http://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/spectral-leakage-zero-padding-and-frequency-resolution.html)) might help you understand further.

Answer (score 0):

A DFT result vector will only provide you with the Fourier series coefficients if (1) the signal is exactly integer periodic within the DFT/FFT length, and (2) the signal (before sampling) is perfectly band-limited to frequencies below Fs/2.  Otherwise, the DFT will contain either window artifacts and/or frequency aliasing.